# Using x-editable (AngularJS) with Drupal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drupal, x-editable

I'm wondering if there is a way to use [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) with Drupal.

P.S : Already there is an [angularJS module](https://drupal.org/project/angularjs) for Drupal.